# Usar próprio blog ou artigo como referência

Tags: debate, suporte

Eu tenho um blog e alguns artigos acadêmicos, o que eu quero saber é se fica deselegante (para não perguntar se é proíbido) eu utilizar uma referência de minha autoria, para complementar a resposta a uma pergunta?

Comment: Deixando claro que é coisa sua, e ocasional, realmente relevante para o assunto não vejo problemas. Desde que a resposta não dependa do recurso externo. E se virar hábito, provavelmente vai acabar caindo em spam, aí geralmente tem consequências bem mais sérias do que ficar "deselegante". O fato é que usar o site como autopromoção "forçada" quase sempre resulta em recepção ruim, então cabe o bom senso de usar quando realmente for agregar valor. Não foram poucas as vezes que respostas foram surgindo com links para o mesmo blog, e hoje nem as contas dos autores existem mais no site ;)

Comment: Como assim uma referencia de sua autoria? A própria resposta não é de sua autoria? rs

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio, sim, digo: eu responder, e linkar um blog que é meu na resposta, como complemento

Comment: @Bacco, nunca o fiz, suspeitava que isso poderia gerar algum tipo de problema.

Comment: @RodrigoSartoriJarouche não seria mais interessante puxar a resposta pra rede?

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio eu coloco nas respostas o suficiente para responder a pergunta. Eu sugiro links para a pessoa poder se aprofundar. P. ex uma pessoa pede como fazer conexão com banco x, eu dou uim exemplo funcional, mas gostaria de sugerir o lin para ela ter informações suplementares...

Comment: @RodrigoSartoriJarouche minha sugestão é usar o bom senso. Se a resposta for completa e suficiente, e no blog tiver um aprofundamento que justifique direcionar pessoas que queiram aprender mais profundamente, sobre detalhes "colaterais", não vejo problemas. Usar resposta só como âncora, sem resolver 100% no site, ai já fica complicado. Lembre-se que na dúvida você pode deixar um comentário embaixo da pergunta, em vez de embutir o link. Mas sempre avisando "Tenho um artigo sobre isso no meu blog", que é para deixar clara a autoria.

Comment: @Bacco por via das dúvidas, eu não vou postar links de minha autoria, já que sempre busco algo oficial ou de algum site reconhecido. Acredito que bom senso cada um tem o seu, e pelo caminhar do debate ( e das negativas na pergunta) isso tem mais a prejudicar do que ajudar.

Comment: @RodrigoSartoriJarouche o risco é alto, vc já percebeu. Mas use o bom senso. Normalmente o pessoal não sai "passando fogo" à toa também, principalmente se vc contribui com outras coisas, e não só com coisa com link seu. Quanto aos negativos, -2 é sinal que tá bem equilibrada a coisa, quando o pessoal é "pesadamente contra" pode apostar que a negativação é mais séria tambem. Quando realmente couber, ponha o link. Se a reação não for boa, só retirar. Se você começasse no site já postando link, ia ser complicado. Um ou outro tendo contribuições regulares muda o cenário.

Comment: @Bacco, boas sugestões, obrigado! Agradeço ao marcelo também!

Comment: Upvoting - acho uma pergunta totalmente relevante. Já vi linkarem sim com blogs e coisas do tipo, mas para *realmente* complementar, e não para responder. O problema é o que repetem aqui diversas vezes: os sites deixam de existir e viram links mortos dentro do stack.

Comment: @RodrigoSartoriJarouche não há problemas em adicionar links externos - é até saudável. Desde que, a sua resposta no SO já seja suficiente para atender a duvida questionada - sem a necessidade de ir no seu blog para ter toda a resposta - e vc adicione o link para seu blog como sugestão de profundamento no assunto. Eu faço isso regularmente, respondo as questões e adiciono um link - para meu blog ou de outros - como "Se quiser saber mais, veja neste artigo".

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi nas respostas já estão me acusando de ter intenção de spam e Black Hat SEO. Acho que meu receio é válido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Além do que o Daniel falou](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5779/1658): as publicações aqui devem ser atemporais.

Imagine que a sua resposta ajudou alguém hoje. Ela é bem pontuada e pode até ser marcada como a resposta correta. Mas daqui a cinco anos, alguém pode ter a mesma dúvida que o OP. Se o seu blog deixar de existir, os links a ele estarão quebrados. Se uma parte essencial da resposta estava no blog, então a resposta deixou de ser útil e deve ser removida do site. Isso acaba por "piorar" a pergunta original sem modificá-la, e sem culpa de seu autor. Por isso toda resposta deve ser auto-contida - links devem ser preferencialmente uma forma de referência, e não caminho para o repositório da solução.

Comment: Eu fui bastante especifico ao dizer "complementar a resposta". E sim, é claro que toda a parte essencial da resposta estaria na própria resposta

Answer (score 3):

Os links para sites terceiros são válidos como referência de origem porém, deixam de ser válidos quando partes essenciais da resposta dependem do recurso externo. Nesse caso, é normalmente sinalizado a moderação, tornando-o passível a exclusão não somente da postagem como da sua conta.

obs: Baseado nos comentários, do jeito que está colocando parece estar mais com intuito de spam ou Black Hat SEO.

Comment: Não poderia descrever melhor